# Construct a matrix using a for loop

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, scipy

I have calculated 9 matrix elements named sij, with i and j being variables (i,j = [1, 2, 3]). Here, i denotes rows and j columns. Suppose I want a 3x3 matrix that consists of the matrix elements s11, s12, ... s32, s33 (nine elements in total).

```
s11 = 1
s12 = 2
s13 = 3
(...)
s33 = 9
```

How can I use for loops to construct a matrix out of these elements? Like this:

```
matrix = [[s11, s12, s13], [s21, s22, s23], [s31, s32, s33]]
```

So that I get a matrix that looks like this.

```
matrix = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

Comment: Use `np.array`/`np.matrix` wrapper?

Comment: You just have a bunch of these variables in your global scope? Why didn't you just add them to a `list` when you generated them, then simply pass that list to the `np.array` constructor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would consider renaming the `sij` to `s[i][j]`. Then using them in loops would be trivial.

```
s[1][1] = 1
s[1][2] = 2
s[1][3] = 3
(...)
s[3][3] = 9
```

Then:

instead of:

```
matrix = [[s11, s12, s13], [s21, s22, s23], [s31, s32, s33]]
```

You can have the following two nested loops to construct the matrix.

```
for i in (1,4):
   for j in (1,4):
```

BTW, having a *0 based* numbering would be more Pythonic.

Answer (score 0):

You are better off writing an array and reshaping such that you don't need to type out elements to variables but here is a one-liner

```
>> np.reshape([eval('s{0}{1}'.format(x,y)) for x in range(1,4) for y in range(1,4)], (3,3))
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9]]
```

Answer (score -1):

We can use this code for creating our desired matrix with for loop:

```
n = int(input('n:'))

for i in range(1,n):

    for j in range(1,n):

        if i<j:
            print(1,end = ' ')
        else :

            print('0',end = ' ')

    print()
```

Output

```
n:5
0 1 1 1 
0 0 1 1 
0 0 0 1 
0 0 0 0
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).